# css3 circular image not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a square picture circular using css 3.

per request posting my entire code
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="home_page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
<span class="image-wrap " style="display:inline-block; background:url(pic1.png);">
<img src="pic1.png" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

css:inside home_page.css

```
.image-wrap {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50em;
    -moz-border-radius: 50em;
    border-radius: 50em;
}
```

Comment: Is `<span class="image-wrap " style="display:inline-block; background:url(pic1.png);">` inside of an element that has the `.circle` class?

Comment: Can you post the full html/css?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the `<img>` to `display: block` and set its `border-radius`, instead of or in addition to the parent element. Also you can use `50%` for circular elements. And remove `opacity: 0` from the image or it will be invisible. I've included a `background-image: url()` example as well, in case that is your issue.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image]

#### CSS:

```css
.circle {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.circle img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
}
.background-circle {
    background-image: url( 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/' );
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="circle"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/" /></div>
<div class="background-circle circle"></div>
```

Comment: Why would this have any effect when the opacity is set to 0?

Comment: @poor Thanks for the fix!